# Hvac/thermostat wiring questions and problems

Tags: thermostat-c-wire, wifi

I have a modular home. My hvac system is a heat pump/ac  with emergency heat strips. It has 5 wires in the wall and my thermostat is battery operated.

I want to install a new Honeywell thermostat with wifi but it requires a 6th wire. According to Honeywell, I am missing a "c"  wire.  They said it could be made to work with the purchase of an adapter but it would sacrifice the use of my heat strips. Does anyone have any knowledge about this? All of the hvac people in my area charging 175.00 plus just to come look at it.

Comment: Many HVAC systems have a "C" (i.e. COMMON) terminal but not all thermostats require it and therefore not all installers connect it.  Have you looked at the wiring diagram for your unit?  Most have it either outside or inside the service panel.  If not, it might help to post the make and model as well as photos of both your thermostat and your HVAC unit connections.  As it is there are far too many details missing to even guess at this.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds right.  Your system needed 5 wires at installation time, so the installer used 5-wire cable instead of 6- or 8-wire to save 2 dollars.  *Upside, the bill was 2 dollars cheaper.*

Best way is to have an old-work electrician fish an 8-wire thermostat cable.  Normally *electricians* are for AC power, so you wouldn't think to call them for an HVAC issue.  But an "old work" electrician has the core skill-set that you require - fishing wires with bare minimum disruption to wall finishes.

I hardly need to explain why it's worth it spending $2 extra on 8-wire cable when you only need 6 right now.

I wouldn't spend any other resources on half-measures or prevarication. Waste of time and money.

I would continue the old thermostat in service using 5 of the 8 wires, simply to confirm everything is still operational.  Then you can pick a spare wire color and assign it to "C" for conversion to the new thermostat.  All the cool kids are using blue.

Comment: Simple technic is pulling a new cable using the old cable. If the old cable are not stapled to structure. Professional electrical contractors are paying for licenses, liability insurance, so their work may be costly.